# Graph transformation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how this codes transforms a file

```
contents <- readFile "graph.txt"
let graph = readGraph contents

readGraph = transpose . str2int . map words . lines
str2int = map.map $ zero2inf . fromIntegral . (\xs -> read xs :: Int)
zero2inf x = if x == 0 then 1/0 else x
```

the actual txt file has the following information

```
0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0
15 13 0  0  0
9  1  8  0  0
1  9  6  1  0
```

could someone give me a description of how the data looks like after the code is run
is it a list? or what is it??

I think the important line here is

```
readGraph = transpose . str2int . map words . lines
```

Comment: Try experimenting with this code in GHCi.

Comment: And checking the types at each step. `:t` (in GHCi) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to know how the actual representation of the graph was and it is a list of lists... something like this

[[1/0,2,5],[2,1/0,6],[5,6,1/0]]

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps.

```
zero2inf :: (Num a, Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a

(\xs -> read xs  :: Int) :: String -> Int
fromIntegral . <prev>    :: Num a => String -> a
zero2inf . <prev>        :: (Num a, Eq a, Fractional a) =>   String   ->   a
map <prev>               :: (Num a, Eq a, Fractional a) =>  [String]  ->  [a]
map <prev>               :: (Num a, Eq a, Fractional a) => [[String]] -> [[a]]
str2int = <prev>

lines                    :: String -> [String]
words                    :: String -> [String]
transpose                :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
map words                :: [String] -> [[String]]
map words . lines        :: String -> [[String]]
str2int . <prev>         :: ( Num a, Fractional a, Eq a )
                            => String -> [[a]]
transpose . <prev>       :: ( Num a, Fractional a, Eq a )
                            => String -> [[a]]

readFile                 :: String -> IO String
readFile "graph.txt"     :: IO String

do contents <- readFile "graph.txt"
   readGraph (contents :: String) :: ( Num a, Fractional a, Eq a ) => [[a]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines` splits an input string on newline characters

`words` splits an input string on whitespace
therefore `map words` is a function which converts a list of strings into a list of list of the words in each string

`map words . lines` therefore converts an input string into a list of list of strings. Given your input, this will be a matrix of strings in row-major order.

Your `str2int` function converts a list of list of strings and converts each element into an `Int` and then converts any zeros into 'infinity' `(1/0)`.

`str2int . map words . lines` therefore reads the input matrix and converts all elements into a numeric type

[Data.List.transpose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose) transposes the rows and columns of its argument, so this just transposes the input matrix into column-major order.

`readGraph` therefore reads an input string containing a matrix in row-major order and converts it into a matrix of `Double`s in column-major order.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can start by writing the code in a form that will run and be compiled by ghc, like this:

```
module Main where

import Data.List

readGraph = transpose . str2int . map words . lines

zero2inf x = if x == 0 then 1/0 else x

str2int = map.map $ zero2inf . fromIntegral . (\xs -> read xs :: Int)
main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "graph.txt"
    print $ readGraph contents
```

But besides that, use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to look at what each individual function in `readGraph` does. `lines` breaks up a string into a list based on the location of newline chars, then `words` is mapped over the list to break each line of integers into separate integers based on the location of spaces, `str2int` transforms each string representing an integer to an actual integer type, and finally `transpose` (like a typical [matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)) exchanges all the rows and columns of the resultant integer matrix.